# Generating a random ID when creating a form in Yii2 framework

Tags: php, web, yii, crud

I am new to Yii. I have this line in a form of a CRUD model:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idmembers')->textInput() ?>
```

I don't want the user to input the ID of the member (PRIMARY KEY), I want it to be generated automatically in the form and the field is disabled.

I replaced textInput() by rand(1,1000) and by random_int(1, 1000) and I get this error when I refresh the page:

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: yii\widgets\ActiveField::random_int()
```

I tried the previous answer, I declared a variable and I used it but still the same problem. Any clues?

Thank's.

Comment: Use an AutoIncrement column in your table, so amend you schema

Comment: You have to fill idmembers property in the controller action and remove textInput() line from view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why you have used  `rand(1,1000)`;

just set `idmembers` `column` as  `AutoIncrement` in `database` as you are saying that it is your `primary field` and just remove this line from your `view`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idmembers')->textInput() ?>// remove this
```

or

if your want this to be generated by rand function then define your method `random_int(1, 1000)`  in your `model`. but this is not good as it will sometime give same no then you will get `dublicate id`.